# Problemas de conexão entre Hibernate com Banco MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Olá, estou iniciando os estudos em Hibernate e não estou fazendo uma conexão com o Banco de Dados MySQL. Segue abaixo o meu código:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
public class Tarefa {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String descricao;
    private boolean finalizado;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Calendar dataFinalizacao;

}
```

Método main:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class GeraTabelas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.
                createEntityManagerFactory("tarefas");
                factory.close();

    }
```

Arquivo Persistence

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd ">
  <persistence-unit name="tarefas">
  <provider> org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider </provider>
  <class>br.com.caelum.tarefas.modelo.Tarefa</class>
  <properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql: //localhost:3306/fj21" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*********" />
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
  </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Quando executo aparece essa mensagem de erro

```
jan 24, 2017 10:43:38 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: tarefas
    ...]
jan 24, 2017 10:43:38 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.7.Final}
jan 24, 2017 10:43:38 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
jan 24, 2017 10:43:39 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
jan 24, 2017 10:43:39 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
jan 24, 2017 10:43:39 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql: //localhost:3306/fj21]
jan 24, 2017 10:43:39 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
jan 24, 2017 10:43:39 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
jan 24, 2017 10:43:39 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at GeraTabelas.main(GeraTabelas.java:8)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to make JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql: //localhost:3306/fj21]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Considerando-se a resposta aceita, votei para fechar isto como erro de digitação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A exceção em questão, assumindo que suas credenciais estão corretas, se deve ao espaço extra na URL JDBC `jdbc:mysql: //localhost:3306/fj21`.

Para resolver o problema edite a URL no arquivo `persistence.xml`.

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fj21" />
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado. Era o espaço extra mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Pelos códigos que mostrasse, pode ser o caminho do banco que você declarou `name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"`. Veja também se a biblioteca, [conector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/), do mysql encontra-se na sua classpath.

Comment: O Conector está na classpath